# how to get correct category of a post in case of multiple categories?

Tags: categories

I have a custom post type called recipes.In this I have lots of recipes as posts.All these recipes are assigned to several categories.

Problem :
Now Consider a post which is assigned to multiple categories. 
On single.php of that post, if i try to retrieve the category of post then I am getting the category which is alphabetically first every time.

I have tried retrieving category from url but it is possible only if I go to recipe template THROUGH the category template...

How to tackle this if we have a post assigned to multiple categories...Please help

Answer (score 2):

If a post has multiple categories there is no "correct" category. Any of them are correct, it's a many-to-one relationship.

Since a post can belong to multiple categories it's a mistake for any function to assume a single category. Expect an array.

If you're looking to apply conditions based on one or more categories you could try `if(has_category($category))` (if you're not in the Loop you'll need to pass the post object as the second parameter).

Edit from comment:

```
if(has_category('fitness')) { 
    // Example custom field 
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fibre', true);
} 
if has_category('children') {
    // Example custom field  
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'protein', true);
}
```

Comment: Actually i have to apply conditions based on category name...if a post belongs to category 'A' then i will print something on single.php of THAT post...else if it belongs to category 'B' then i will print something else on single.php of THAT post...and so on...Is this possible for a post with multiple categories? If i cant retrieve that category then i cant apply conditions based on it.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: ok so has_category doesn't really serve my purpose as it will tell me if a post has that category or not....I cant use that much information to apply category specific conditions....Your initial answer pretty much explained the whole scenario...thanks a lot

Comment: You can easily use that - if( has_category( $cat ) ) { /* $cat-specific stuff here */ }`

Comment: I am sorry...I am not getting the logic....If a post is in category A and category B, then...

if (has_category('category A'))  { category specific code for 'A' }...
else if (has_category('category 'B'))  { category specific code for 'B' }...

this is fine but I cant really avoid clash of two categories....Because both conditions ARE NOT mutually exclusive..they both are true at the same time..

Comment: You can test for membership of two specific categories with `if(has_category('foo') && has_category('bar'))` or check if it's a member of a specific category and has one or more other categories with `if(has_category('foo') && count(wp_get_post_categories()) > 1)` - there may be a better way to do it depending on your desired results, but I can't see exactly what you're looking to output based on the category you retrieve. Could you give an example of the output as used for your recipes?

Comment: Ok so here's an example...

say, Mango Salad is in category 'fitness' and category 'children'
Now I go to the single.php of  Mango Salad..

If its in category 'fitness' then i have to print fibre content of Mango Salad in single.php...
If its in category 'children' then I have to print protein content of Mango Salad in single.php....

Both this nutrition values I have readily available in fields...I need to print them depending on categories in single.php

This is exactly what I want

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: ok but wont this logic print both the fibre and protein??Both the if conditions are true here

Comment: sorry..still waiting for reply